# Display button in center and text at the left

Tags: css, position, center

Faced up with quite trivial problem I think but I can't solve it. Maybe you've got the right solution.

I need to center the button and display text at left of that button. It should be responsive so the option with position:absolute is not good here.
Are there any other solutions to achieve this?

The visual sketch of what I want it is here
[image]

Will be very appreciated for any advice from you.

Comment: Do you have many or just one line of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should resolve the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/waquwa47/

```
<div style="text-align: right;">
Text here
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<button>
Button
</button>
</div>
<div>
&nbsp;
</div>

div{
float: left;
width: 33.333%;
height: auto;
overflow: auto;
background-color: #FFF;
}
```